# How to display data from a sqlite database in assets folder?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I want to display data from test.db in the assets folder on the list view. I've searched the internet but haven't found it yet. This is an example of my databasehelper.

In the test.db database there are [numbers, names, schools]. How do I display the data?
I want to display data from test.db in the assets folder on the list view. I've searched the internet but haven't found it yet. This is an example of my databasehelper.

In the test.db database there are [numbers, names, schools]. How do I display the data?
I want to display data from test.db in the assets folder on the list view. I've searched the internet but haven't found it yet. This is an example of my databasehelper.

In the test.db database there are [numbers, names, schools]. How do I display the data?

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private final Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/databases/";
    private final String USER_TABLE = "user";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        createDb();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public void createDb(){
        boolean dbExist = checkDbExist();

        if(!dbExist){
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            copyDatabase();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDbExist(){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = null;

        try{
            String path = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (Exception ex){
        }

        if(sqLiteDatabase != null){
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void copyDatabase(){
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

            String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while ((length = inputStream.read(b)) > 0){
                outputStream.write(b, 0, length);
            }

            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private SQLiteDatabase openDatabase(){
        String path = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        return db;
    }
    public void close(){
        if(db != null){
            db.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I display the data?

You need to decide how/where you want the data to be displayed. Assuming in an Activity and via a ListView then:-

You would then extract the data via a query, probably using the [SQLiteDatabase **query** method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) retrieving a Cursor.

You could then, via a Cursor Adapter e.g. [SimpleCursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter)

- Note that a column specifically named **_id** is required for CursorAdapters and that this should be an alias of the [**rowid**](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) column.

display the rows in a **ListView**.

## Putting it together

The following code (note only shows name and School in the list, you can create a layout to suit) is a working example based upon the database (**test.db**) containing a table named **user** that has columns **numbers**, **name** and **school**

- **Note** the databasehelper has been changed to cope with Android 9+

### DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static String DATABASE_PATH;
    private final Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    //private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/"; //<<<<<<<<<< no need to hard code anything see below
    public final static String USER_TABLE = "user";
    public final static String USER_NUMBERS_COLUMN = "numbers";
    public final static String USER_NAME_COLUMN = "name";
    public final static String USER_SCHOOL_COLUMN = "school";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        DATABASE_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath(); //<<<<<<<<<< Recommended way
        createDb();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public void createDb() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDbExist();

        if (!dbExist) {
            //this.getReadableDatabase(); //<<<<<<<< will mess up Android 9 as it creates -wal and -shm files
            copyDatabase();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDbExist() {

        /**
         * Checks the file instead of trying to open the database,
         * makes directories if needed (the get around to this was opening the database to create them)
         */
        File db = new File(DATABASE_PATH);
        if (!db.exists()) {
            if(!new File(db.getParent()).exists()) {
                new File(db.getParent()).mkdirs();
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

        /* Done away with unreliable method
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = null;
        try {
            String path = DATABASE_PATH;
            sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        if (sqLiteDatabase != null) {
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        */
    }

    private void copyDatabase() {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
            String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(b)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(b, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
        String path = DATABASE_PATH;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        return db;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Extract all columns for all rows adding column _id for CursorAdapter
     */
    public Cursor getAllMyData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns = new String[]{"*,rowid AS " + BaseColumns._ID};
        return db.query(
                USER_TABLE,columns,
                null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

- Notes

  - see comments for some explanations
  - some old code has been left in but commented out

### MainActivity.java

This is the activity that was used and includes a ListView

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;
    Cursor mCsr;
    ListView mUserList;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;
        mUserList = this.findViewById(R.id.userlist); //<<<<<<<<<< id of the ListView
        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this); //Instantiate the database helper
        setupOrRefreshTheListView();
    }

    private void setupOrRefreshTheListView() {
        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getAllMyData();
        if (mSCA == null) {
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    mCsr,
                    // Columns from the Cursor to include in the ListView (must have a corresponding view in the layout)
                    new String[]{
                            DatabaseHelper.USER_NAME_COLUMN,
                            DatabaseHelper.USER_SCHOOL_COLUMN
                    },
                    // Views in the ListView into which the Data is placed (must correspond with Column in the Cursor)
                    new int[]{
                            android.R.id.text1,
                            android.R.id.text2},
                    0
            );
            mUserList.setAdapter(mSCA);
            // Add an on item click listener in this case Toasts data
            mUserList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            mContext,
                            "You clicked the row with an ID of " + String.valueOf(id) +
                                    " Name is " + mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.USER_NAME_COLUMN)) +
                                    " School is " + mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.USER_SCHOOL_COLUMN)) +
                                    " Numbers is " + String.valueOf(mCsr.getInt(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.USER_NUMBERS_COLUMN))),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            mSCA.swapCursor(mCsr); // This reapplies the Cursor to reflect any changes
        }
    }
}
```

The above has been run on API 21 (Lollipop) and also 28 (Pie). The folowing is an example screen shot :-

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Btw you image doen't show. I can't access your image

Comment: @MuhammadDianNafi np. Not sure about the image, I used the cut and paste so it's stored on/at imgur perhaps you have the site blocked for some reason. Not that it's that important if you've got the code working.